# How to filter out duplicate names with returned JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

[image]

I have multiple same name data from a JSON response. I'm looking to write a function that will filter out the same name data on my options list.

```js
const select = document.getElementById('brand');
/**===============Fetch requests=========== */

        fetch("http://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products.json")
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function(data) {
            let products = data;
            return products.map(function(product) {
            console.log(product.brand);
          })
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });

        fetch("http://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products.json")
         .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((resp) => generateOptions(resp))

/*===========Helper Functions====================== */
      function generateOptions(data) {
        let products = data;
        const options = products.map(item => `
          <option value='${item.brand}'>${item.brand}</option>
        `).join('');
        select.innerHTML = options;
        
      }
```

Comment: What does the response data look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your questions is that the response contains multiple products which have the same `brand` name.

There are multiple ways you could do it. If the expectation of the drop down is to just contain the brands, then a new API could just return all the brands and the relevant metadata. So get `brands` would return an array of unique brand objects.

If you want to do it with the existing request that you have, you can iterate over the response and create a separate `Set` of brand names. Set in JavaScript:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

A set won’t allow you to have duplicate keys. 
You can then iterate over the set to create the HTML select options.

Comment: Yes, the expectation is to just have a drop-down of brand names, I can't seem to create a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

take advantage of the new Map

```js
const duplicates = [['dior', 'data'], ['iman', 'data'], ['dior, iman']]
const dedup = new Map(duplicates)
```